# How can I access an object's properties in a reduce function?

Tags: dataweave

I'm converting an array of objects to an object of key:value pairs, where the value is an string aggregation. My challenge is that I do not now how to access *obj* properties, while using `reduce ( (env,obj={})`

Currently I can weave the following payload:

```
{
"records": [{
            "MetadataComponentName": "ClassB",
            "RefMetadataComponentName": "ClassC"
        },{
            "MetadataComponentName": "ClassA",
            "RefMetadataComponentName": "ClassB"
        }
    ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "ClassB": "ClassC",
  "ClassA": "ClassB",
}
```

But the goal is to achieve:

```
{
  "ClassA": "ClassB,ClassC",
}
```

The script is:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.records reduce (
    (env,obj={}) ->        
            obj ++ {
            (env.MetadataComponentName):env.RefMetadataComponentName
             }
)
```

And I've tested accessing *obj* in a conditional as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.records reduce (
    (env,obj={}) ->        
        if ((obj['MetadataComponentName']=="ClassB"))
            obj ++ {
            (env.MetadataComponentName):env.RefMetadataComponentName
             }
        else null
)
```

which produces a null result!  Negating the conditional - `if (!(obj['MetadataComponentName']=="ClassB")) obj ++ {` produces the same output as without the conditional at all.

My intended logic would be to ultimately prevent deduplicating keys:

```
if (!(obj['MetadataComponentName']==env.MetadataComponentName))
            obj ++ {
            (env.MetadataComponentName):env.RefMetadataComponentName
             }
        else 
            (env.MetadataComponentName): obj['MetadataComponentName'] + env.RefMetadataComponentName
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to access an object's property's in the reduce function?
- Is `obj['MetadataComponentName']` the correct syntax to retrieve a value?
- Is the correct solution to define a function that performs this key dedupe?

Thoughts and opinions much appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid making multiple questions in one in Stackoverflow. I would recommend to explain in more detail the problem that you are trying to resolve rather than asking about implementing a specific solution. There could be alternative solutions that could be suggested understanding the original problem.

Comment: Thanks Aled.  As mentioned in the post:
_My intended logic would be to ultimately prevent deduplicating keys_.
Hence why I needed to access and evaluate the accumulator's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that reduce works on arrays, and the state it keeps is just an accumulator and the current element. I don't understand why do see a limitation on accessing the properties of the object. Your scripts access the properties correctly in different ways.

It looks just that you are trying to use reduce() in a way that is not well matched to it. I recommend to keep it simple and use reduce to accumulate the values you need in an easy way to operate, then transform that in the expected result.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var result=payload.records 
    reduce (
        (env,obj={lastKey: null, names:[]}) ->        
            {
            lastKey: env.MetadataComponentName,
            names: ([env.RefMetadataComponentName] ++ obj.names)  
            }
    )
---
{ (result.lastKey): result.names joinBy ","}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "ClassA": "ClassB,ClassC"
}
```

The result is what was asked. I'm not sure if the algorithm I used is the one you want because the **logic** that you were trying to achieve was not clarified in the question.

Using `obj.MetadataComponentName` and `obj['MetadataComponentName']` give the same result. The second form is the [dynamic selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors#dynamic_selector) one usually used with the index being expressions or variables rather than literal strings.

Comment: Thanks again Aled.  You've answered the two main questions:
_Is it possible to access an object's property's in the reduce function?
Is obj['MetadataComponentName'] the correct syntax to retrieve a value?_

Now that I know this is appropriate, I need to continue investigating why `(obj['MetadataComponentName']=="ClassB")` never evaluates to true.

I'll likely have to move from the playground environment and set up an instance that I can debug / breakpoint.

Many thanks again.